# Ending of "91 Days"

Tags: 91-days

At the end of *91 Days*, Angelo and Nero are walking on the beach and after Angelo walks past him, Nero

> aims his pistol and fires a shot.

We never really see what happens to Angelo, as Nero drives off (with a can of pineapples?) and their footsteps are washed away by the ocean surf.

Did Angelo

> get shot? Or was this another replay of the shot from 9 years ago when Nero's shot missed Angelo when he was a kid running away?

And I probably missed something at some point, but why the pineapples?

Answer (score 6):

Whether Avilio is shot is unclear, and it's only really speculation as to his fate.

There's a seemingly elaborate fan theory analysing the shoe patterns, shoe styles and footsteps made in the sand. This fan theory seems to think that Avilio was not shot. You can read the full post and check the screenshots on the Reddit discussion [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/anime/comments/559bjy/spoilers_91_days_episode_12_discussion_final/d89494h).

The '*Pineapples in the backseat*' are a little more explainable, however.

In Episode 4, while they're (Nero and Avilio) on the run from the assassin tracking them, they're in a store and Avilio is doing the shopping. Avilio picks up cans of pineapples in a hurry. Nero later comments and jokes about his choice.

The can of pineapple in the backseat of the car is a momento of that moment they shared together (and could be seen as a representation of Nero saving his life)

[image]  [image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The footprints that continue are Nero's. The ones that stop are Angelo's. Making it appear that someone either backtracked in their steps or teleported to another location.

Both of which are highly unlikely. Even if Angelo was shot and fell to the left into the surf, it wasn't high enough to pull his body out to sea. Nero didn't drag it out because his stride never changed in the sand. Angelo stops and sidesteps to his left. The waves are already coming up to the pair of prints closest to the ocean, so anything to the left of those would've been washed away.

The only plausible explanation is that Angelo is alive and soaking his feet in the water after an extremely long drive. He and Nero parted ways, as Nero continued walking and drove away. Meanwhile, Angelo continued walking in the surf and exited at another point, where his footprints continued.

Answer (score -1):

I just finished watching *91 Days*. The 12th episode is little confusing, although this pineapple can was bought during flee along with some other food, like in the restaurant.

During their sea walk, Avilio said:

> Do you know why you are still alive?
>   Cause I didn't want to kill you

Then with the same expression of rage, confusion, and happiness on his face, Nero pulled a shot as a reply:

> Now you know, why you are still alive?
>   Cause I didn't want to, either.

Also, while coming back in the car, the type of happy expression Nero made was of recent meeting with a new friend or of a recent new relationship (just friends in this case).Those who know facial expression reading can easily judge it.

Moreover, the new Don asked Avilio to kill Nero as a favor. So it might be a play between them. As we can see, our new Don's man crossed Nero and stopped. Maybe he would notice Avilio's wound as his failure.

Still, out of 91 only 12 days have been completed. So the anime will likely continue.

Answer (score -1):

It shows at the end he didn't die, it just doesn't show you. There are 2 prints of sets slowly getting washed away where they walked together. Then a single set walking on that gets washed away, where he continues to walk the beach, (also Angelo) never seeing the sea before, hinting at the fact he is still alive.

Throughout the dub, there were drops of hidden stuff that never get addressed and are on the viewer specifically to pick it up. One was when they are at the docks and Angelo says 'You know I had a kid brother like you once (<- ding ding), I should introduce you sometime'

---

Speculation:

Nero already knows he's dead anyway after driving so far and still having the mafia find them. So, regardless of what he wanted to do, he had to part ways. Angelo was also talking at the fire about after achieving his goal, he still didn't have a reason to live hence why he said 'You know, you don't need a reason to live, you just live.'
Why would he be saying what to do if he intended to kill him?

Comment: "It shows at the end he didnt die, it just doesn't show you" - that's not very clear. Does it show that he survived or doesn't it?